# R: Fast way to create a sparse model matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to create a model matrix with a formula that has many interaction terms (some continuous, some 0-1, some factors with many levels).  The creation of this model matrix is the bottleneck of my script. In the end the model matrix is 8M rows with 1000 columns. Since the factors with many levels are 0-1 encoded the resulting matrix representing interactions is very sparse, so I already use `sparse.model.matrix`.

Is there a faster way to generate this matrix? Perhaps in Rcpp?

Comment: maybe profile `sparse.model.matrix` to see where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: It would be nice if you''d provide a MWE too so we could get a better idea of what you dealing with.

Comment: For further comparison see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373710/r-fast-way-to-create-a-sparse-model-matrix

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using `caret`'s `dummyVars`?  It works for me and seems reasonably fast.

`?dummyVars` compares the default behavior of `model.matrix` and `dummyVars`, but doesn't say much about it.

For a small performance benchmark on a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
n = 1e3 # observations
m = 1e2 # variables
some_levels <- sort(c(LETTERS, letters))
library('microbenchmark')
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
       lapply(1:m, function(x){
                    switch(sample.int(3,1),    
                           # "some continuous, some 0-1"
                           '1' = rnorm(n), '2' = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
                           # "some factors with many levels"       
                           '3' = factor(sample(some_levels, n, TRUE),
                                        levels=some_levels )
                          )
                        })
               )
names(df) <- paste0('V',1:m)

#------------- it sounds like you are doing something like this --------------
frm <- as.formula( paste('~', paste(names(df), collapse='+') ) )
library('Matrix')
microbenchmark(
  mm <- sparse.model.matrix(frm, df)
) # mean = .133 sec (YMMV)

#---------------- you could try something like this --------------------------
library('caret')
microbenchmark(
  mm2 <- dummyVars(frm, df, fullRank=TRUE)
) # mean = .00954 sec (YMMV)
```

Note `fullRank = TRUE` so that "factors are encoded to be consistent with `model.matrix` and the resulting there [sic] are no linear dependencies induced between the columns," per `?dummyVars`.  You might want to remove `fullRank = TRUE` to induce the behavior of `sparse=TRUE` in `contr.ltrf` as in `sparse.model.matrix`.  I could not find clear documentation.

Comment: Doesn't `dummyVars` just create a map?  Don't you need a predict statement too?  Like `mm3 <- predict(mm2, df)`?